# __str__ to give a visual representation of the 2D table in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I am using the below **str** function in my program to represent 2D table

```
def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the table"""
        return ('\n'.join(['|'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in self._table]))
```

which gives me below output if i use str()

```
'1|2|3\n2|4|6\n3|6|9'
```

how do i get it to dislay as below with out using print()

```
1|2|3
2|4|6
3|6|9
```

i tried to define my **str** as below :

```
def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the table"""
        return print(('\n'.join(['|'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in self._table])))
```

which gives output with below error using str()

```
1|2|3
2|4|6
3|6|9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    str(MultiplicationTable(3))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: That's not how `__str__` works, you're supposed to print whatever `__str__` returns, not print it out in `__str__`... please read the documentation on how to use these functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
return print(('\n'.join(['|'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in self._table])))
```

Your `__str__` function is actually returning the result of the `print` function (which is `NoneType` because nothing is returned by `print`), not the string of your 2d table. Leading you to get this error, because `__str__` should return a string. It should be:

```
return ('\n'.join(['|'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in self._table]))
```

Comment: when i use return ('\n'.join(['|'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in self._table]))    the output is '1|2|3\n2|4|6\n3|6|9' , how to get str() output as a table   with out using print statement